# Translate a construction into categorical languages

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, soft-question, higher-category-theory

Let $\mathscr C$ be a category whose objects are sets.
Let $\mathscr V$ be another category. It seems that the usual composition in $\mathscr V$ can be somehow 'twisted' by $\mathscr C$. I notice that we have a category-like stuff $\mathscr V(\mathscr C)$ as follows. It is not really a category but let's temporarily pretend it is.

'Objects' are the same as $\mathscr V$. Fix an object $A\in\mathscr C$. For $V_1,V_2\in\mathscr V$, we consider
$$
Mor^A(V_1,V_2)=\prod_{a\in A} Hom_{\mathscr V}(V_1,V_2)
$$
Namely, its element $\phi$ is an $A$-family $(\phi^a)_{a\in A}$ of morphisms in $\mathscr V$.
Perhaps it would be helpful to assume both $\mathscr C$ and $\mathscr V$ are (sub)categories of vector spaces, and then we may think of $Mor^A(V_1,V_2)$ as the space $Hom_{Vect}(A\times V_1, V_2)$ of bilinear maps.

In the next, given a morphism $g:A\to B$ in $\mathscr C$, we have something like a composition as follows:
$$
\circ_g: Mor^B(V_2,V_3)\times Mor^A(V_1,V_2) \to Mor^A(V_1,V_3)
$$
The image $\psi\circ_g\phi$ of $\psi=(\psi^b)_{b\in B}$ and $\phi=(\phi^a)_{a\in A}$ is given by
$$
(\psi\circ_g\phi)^a= \psi^{g(a)}\circ \phi^a, \qquad a\in A
$$
Moreover, if we have another $h:B\to C$ in $\mathscr C$ and cook up $\circ_h$ and $\circ_{hg}$ in the same way, then by some routine computation we can check that
$$
\eta\circ_{hg}( \psi \circ_g \phi)= (\eta\circ_h \psi)\circ_g \phi
$$

**Question:** I am not quite expert in the category theories. I was wondering if there already exists a terminology for such a construction. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to give a look to the example 4 in this webpage: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copower.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example you're looking at?

Comment: You might also be interested in the definition of [indexed category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/indexed+category).

Comment: @Fosco Thank you. I think the indexed category you mentioned is exactly what I want. For my purpose, I was wondering if we can develop $S$-indexed category for not just a category $S$ but also a 2-category or even an $\infty$-category $S$.

Comment: @Fosco The link you attached here defines an $S$-indexed category to be a pseudofunctor (weak 2-functor) from $S^{op}$ to the 2-category $\underline{Cat}$. So we should expect $S$ is also a bicategory (or 2-category). How do you think?